# IntelliJIDEA LoginException

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, exception, glassfish

In PostgreSQL, I have created role, lets say "example_role" in pgAdmin3, and tried to login in command promt and on glassfish server, which works in both cases, but not when I try to start the server with IntelliJIDEA, in which case I get the following exception:

```
        Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason:
        java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Exception while processing command: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException
```

And server gives me following output (Im using Maven for project packaging):

```
C:\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain --debug example_domain
[2014-04-08 08:30:30,003] Artifact scrumkin-ear:ear: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
Debugging is enabled and the server is suspended.  Please attach to the debugging port at: 9009
Attempting to start example_domain.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:9009', transport: 'socket'
```

I have provided exact same username and password inside IntelliJIDEA for the specified glassfish server, so I don't know what else could be causing the error. In eclipse, for example, I have no issues!

Comment: `Please look at the server log for more details.....` ....

Comment: the first exception is from server log... anyway I found out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL was wrong, it was left default, which worked for "postgres" user, and also at some moment for other roles/users too, which is very strange...